# how to create table with fields in command line Centos

Tags: centos, command-line, mysql

How do I do this in command line?

Below is code i saw imported to PhpmyAdmin  but i don't use any interface...

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
`id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`product_code` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`product_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`product_desc` tinytext NOT NULL,
`product_img_name` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
`price` decimal(10,2) NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
UNIQUE KEY `product_code` (`product_code`)
) AUTO_INCREMENT=1 ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is for MySQL (or MariaDB), and you have the above as the contents of a file named `table_create.sql`:

```
$ mysql --user=$USERID --password=$PASSWD --database=$DB < table_create.sql
```

You have to know what your MySQL user ID and password are, and know the database name. Substitute those strings as appropriate for the apparent "shell variables" in the above command.

It's probably advisable to have your table creation in a file, so as to be able to repeat that creation *when* you screw up, but if you must do it at the command line:

```
$ mysql -u $USER -p
Enter password:
...
MariaDB [(none)]> use yourdatabase
Database changed
MariaDB [yourdatabase]> CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `products` (
    -> `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    -> `product_code` varchar(60) NOT NULL,
    -> ...
    -> );
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.24 sec)
```

Comment: I mean how can I do it without importing sql file just do it directly in command? I've created database store and table products successfully but now I need to preferably add name, description and price fields...?

Comment: @cea - see edited answer.

Comment: thanks - now i need to find out what VARCHAR means and what number to set for each field

Comment: @cea - MariaDB data types: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/data-types/  `varchar(80)` is a character string, of maximum length 80 characters. 80 characters can mean a lot more than 80 bytes if you use UTF-8 character  set, and non-Latin (Cyrillic, Mandarin, etc) characters.

Comment: ACTUALLY your code worked perfectly :)

Answer (score 1):

`mysql -u<user>  -p<pass> somedb -B -e "<insert your commands here>"`